# What is allowed in the Mercurial INI (hgrc) ui "merge" option?

Tags: mercurial

Mercurial can be configured using a `mercurial.ini` (or `.hgrc`) file. In the `[ui]` section ([docs](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#ui)) there is a `merge` option.

This option is only documented as follows:

> merge
>
> The conflict resolution program to use during a manual merge.

In my current configuration I just have the line:

`merge = kdiff3`

But what is the allowed syntax for this setting? For instance, can I provide command line options to the specified program? Can I use an absolute path? etc.

Thanks

---

Note - the above cited docs do suggest looking in another link for more related information (https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#merge-tools) but this does not specifically cover the configuration section I am interested in.

Comment: this page provides more information: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach isn't to add options to the `[ui]\merge` entry but instead to further configure the merge tool elsewhere.

The page on kdiff3 in the mercurial wiki is more elaborate on how you can [configure kdiff3 with mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KDiff3) by using the `[extdiff]` and `[merge-tools]` sections. Excerpt:

```
[extensions]
hgext.extdiff =

[extdiff]
cmd.kdiff3 =

[merge-tools]
kdiff3.args = $base $local $other -o $output
```

That will add a new graphical diff command `hg kdiff3` (using ExtdiffExtension), and tells Mercurial to use kdiff3 for merges.

Comment: Thanks for providing the key information. I added a few comments to elaborate slightly just based on what I learned in understanding your answer.